# Seems something is wrong when trying to set requestPointerLock()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, pointerlock

It seems something is wrong in my code, but I cannot figure what. I am trying to call pointerlockchange api to disable pointer and use mouse as fps controller. The problem is that always **pointerlockerror** is triggered and I get a *Error setting pointer lock!* message.

The function is called inside **$(document).ready**. Here's the code.:

```
function initLock() {
var havePointerLock = 'pointerLockElement' in document || 'mozPointerLockElement' in document || 'webkitPointerLockElement' in document;

if ( havePointerLock ) {
    var element = document.body;
    console.log('Cathing element', element);
    var pointerlockchange = function ( event ) {
        if ( document.pointerLockElement === element || document.mozPointerLockElement === element || document.webkitPointerLockElement === element ) {
            controls.enabled = true;
            console.log('Pointer lock enabled!')
        } 
        else {
            controls.enabled = false;
        }
    }

    var pointerlockerror = function ( event ) {
        console.log('Error setting pointer lock!');
    }

    // Hook pointer lock state change events
    document.addEventListener( 'pointerlockchange', pointerlockchange, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'mozpointerlockchange', pointerlockchange, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'webkitpointerlockchange', pointerlockchange, false );

    document.addEventListener( 'pointerlockerror', pointerlockerror, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'mozpointerlockerror', pointerlockerror, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'webkitpointerlockerror', pointerlockerror, false );


    // Ask the browser to lock the pointer
    element.requestPointerLock = element.requestPointerLock || element.mozRequestPointerLock || element.webkitRequestPointerLock;

    if ( /Firefox/i.test( navigator.userAgent ) ) {
        var fullscreenchange = function ( event ) {
            if ( document.fullscreenElement === element || document.mozFullscreenElement === element || document.mozFullScreenElement === element ) {
                document.removeEventListener( 'fullscreenchange', fullscreenchange );
                document.removeEventListener( 'mozfullscreenchange', fullscreenchange );
                element.requestPointerLock();
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener( 'fullscreenchange', fullscreenchange, false );
        document.addEventListener( 'mozfullscreenchange', fullscreenchange, false );

        element.requestFullscreen = element.requestFullscreen || element.mozRequestFullscreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullscreen;
        element.requestFullscreen();
    } 
    else {
        element.requestPointerLock();
    }
} 
else {
    console.log('Sorry, pointer lock cannot be set.');
}
```

}

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found solution by myself. The problem is that requestPointerLock cannot be called automatically, it should be called from the user's callback, for example, when clicking on something.

Comment: You can call `requestPointerLock()` directly if the user has accepted a fullscreen request (https://w3c.github.io/pointerlock/). However, I found implementation differences between FF and Chrome (Ubuntu) with respect to subsequent calls to `exitPointerLock()` and `requestPointerLock()`. FF implementation seems closes to W3C spec.